# Vue 3: Tree Menu Show

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

To be clear what I want to do...
When `Menu 1` is Clicked, its `ul` will be shown and likewise if `Menu 1` is shown `ul`, and `Menu 1` is Clicked, `ul` is not displayed.
same applies to `Menu 2`

Can you show me as an example how can I do what I want to do?

`Menu 1` Click `Menu 1` **ul show** or **ul show** close

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in menuData" :key="index">
      <router-link :to="item.path" exact @click.stop="showMenu(index)">{{ item.name }}</router-link>
      <ul v-if="item.children" v-show="showCollapsed">
        <li v-for="(childItem,ChildIndex) in item.children" :key="ChildIndex">
          <router-link :to="childItem.path">{{ childItem.name }}</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      openshow: false,
      selected: null,
      menuData: [{name: "Home", path: "/",}, {name: "About", path: "/about",}, {name: "Menu 1", path: "#", children: [{name: "Menu 1.1", path: "/menu/1/1",}, {name: "Menu 1.2", path: "/menu/1/2",}, {name: "Menu 1.3", path: "/menu/1/3",},],}, {name: "Menu 2", path: "#", children: [{name: "Menu 2.1", path: "/menu/2/1",}, {name: "Menu 2.2", path: "/menu/2/2",}, {name: "Menu 2.3", path: "/menu/2/3",},],}, {name: "Gallery", path: "/gallery",}, {name: "Contact", path: "/contact",},],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showMenu(index) {
      this.selected = index;
    },
    showCollapsed() {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `showMenu` method with passed index and then check what `ul` to show passing index to `showCollapsed` :

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
   data() {
    return {
      openshow: false,
      selected: null,
      menuData: [{name: "Home", path: "/",}, {name: "About", path: "/about",}, {name: "Menu 1", path: "#", children: [{name: "Menu 1.1", path: "/menu/1/1",}, {name: "Menu 1.2", path: "/menu/1/2",}, {name: "Menu 1.3", path: "/menu/1/3",},],}, {name: "Menu 2", path: "#", children: [{name: "Menu 2.1", path: "/menu/2/1",}, {name: "Menu 2.2", path: "/menu/2/2",}, {name: "Menu 2.3", path: "/menu/2/3",},],}, {name: "Gallery", path: "/gallery",}, {name: "Contact", path: "/contact",},],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showMenu(index) {
      this.selected === index ? this.selected = null : this.selected = index;
    },
    showCollapsed(idx) {
      return idx === this.selected || false
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in menuData" :key="index" @click="showMenu(index)">
      <router-link :to="item.path" exact>{{ item.name }}</router-link>
      <ul v-if="item.children" v-show="showCollapsed(index)">
        <li v-for="(childItem,ChildIndex) in item.children" :key="ChildIndex">
          <router-link :to="childItem.path">{{ childItem.name }}</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you just noticed, this is not what I want,
doesn't get exactly what I want
`v-show="index === selected"`
I want to run a function instead and I want to show it depending on the function.

Comment: @Rapunzel hey mate , did you try the snippet, it is doing what you described in your question, or am I wrong?

Comment: ok it works but that's not exactly what I want, namely, when `Menu 1` is open, I want it to close when `Menu 1` is clicked again. it does not provide

Comment: check again pls

Comment: ok now it works, `v-show="index === selected"` but is it possible to write the function instead? `showCollapsed()`

Comment: you're right, but that's not the exact answer I want :) What I want is 90% OF, 10% has the remainder :) `showCollapsed()`

Comment: I'm waiting for you, for me to accept your answer.

Comment: here is your function :)